# Работа с draw9patch: изображение с черными точками

Tags: android

1. Загрузила изображение в draw9patch.
2. Выделила чёрными линиями и точками область масштабирования и область размещения контента. Вроде должно быть всё хорошо. Сохранила File->Save 9-patch.
3. Загрузила изображение в папку drawable.
4. Поставила фоном у EditText'а.
5. В итоге я увидела изображение с чёрными точками, а текст не отобразился так, как надо.

Скажите, где ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте [этот](http://weblookandfeel.com/downloads/ninepatch-demo.jar) редактор, простой, удобный! У меня проблем не было!

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!! Помогло!!! Хотя ранее делала в стандартном редакторе!

Answer (score 2):

Первое - имя файла должно быть вида `res/drawable/filename.9.png`. 
В xml файле прописать так:

```
<Button
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/filename" />
```

Comment: у меня всё так и есть.

Comment: <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/searsch"
        android:singleLine="true" />

Comment: а изображение searsch.9.png я положила в папку drawable